# Can I access to touched node properties in touchBegan method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I want to know a property of the touched node and then change it without using node name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the `touchesBegan` method override you have full access to `self.` so can do anything you want with the node from there.

Similarly, in the other `touchesEnded`, `touchesMoved`

If you're coming from Unity, the biggest difference is the lack of `update` and `fixedUpdate` access inside the nodes. You can only get at this game loop stuff from within the Scene node.

However... if you use [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/), you can use Entities, and then think in much the same way you would in Unity about composition and the game loop.